# How to break dynamic json data into two lines after first comma only?

Tags: jquery

How to display dynamic json data into two lines after first comma only? Example my data is " sam T. Sam, france, italy"  I want "sam T. Sam," in one line and "france, italy" in next line....comma should not be replaced....is there a way to achieve this in javascript or jquery?

Json data in anchor tag =  abc d. E. Dfg, gf, gg
I want to display as below

Line1= abc d. E. Dfg,
Line2= gf, gg

Comment: hi my friend can post html please

Comment: So basically you want to add a line break after the first encountered comma?

Answer (score 0):

using JQUERY :
for every Anchor element split by comma then add new line and keep comma

`$('a').each(function(){
  el=$(this).html();
  $(this).html(el.substring(0,el.indexOf(','))+',<BR>'+el.slice(el.indexOf(',')+1));
    });`

or this if you want to split  on every comma

`$('a').each(function(){
 $(this).html($(this).html().split(',').join(',<BR>'));
});`

https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/hr64cget/